# pipe streams to edit csv file in node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, stream

I am basically trying to :

- open a csv file as a stream
- make some operation on each line
- stream the result into a second csv file

in node.js.

Here is my code :

```
var fs = require("fs");
var csv = require("csv");

var readStream = fs.createReadStream("input.csv");
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("output.csv");

var csvStream = csv
    .parse()
    .on("data", function(data){
    //do some stuff with data
    return(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
    .on("end", function(){
        console.log("done");
    })
    .on("error", function(error){
        console.log(error)
    });

(readStream.pipe(csvStream)).pipe(writeStream);
```

I am getting "TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk". What am I doing wrong ? I am totally new to node.js, so please detail your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading correctly the data. However using `return` is not the correct way to transform your data. CSV Stream cannot at the same time output untransformed data (that you are reading in your `data` event handler) and transformed data that you would pipe to `writeStream`.

To use `pipe` with the writeStream, you would have needed a readableStream outputing your transformed data. That would have meant creating a read/write stream around your transform function, and piping `fileReader > csvReader > transformStream > writeStream`.
It is way simpler to attach a function to the `data` event of the csv reader like you did, but you need to manually write to the file.

Correct code code may be more clear this way :

```
var fs = require("fs");
var csv = require("csv");

var readStream = fs.createReadStream("input.csv"); // readStream is a read-only stream wit raw text content of the CSV file
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("output.csv"); // writeStream is a write-only stream to write on the disk

var csvStream = csv.parse(); // csv Stream is a read and write stream : it reads raw text in CSV and output untransformed records

csvStream.on("data", function(data) {
  //console.log(data)

  writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(data));
})
.on("end", function(){
    console.log("done");
})
.on("error", function(error){
    console.log(error)
});

readStream.pipe(csvStream)
```

Comment: Does the stream-transform module offer any benefits? https://csv.js.org/transform/ . I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

I have basically done these:

parsed (read csv strings and writes objects and arrays)
  stringified (reads objects and arrays and writes csv strings)
  piped all that to writeStream to my file

```js
function readingAppendingAndWritingToCSVFile(readStream, writeStream) {
  const results = [];
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readStream.pipe(csv.parse({ columns: true }))
    .on('data', (data) => {
      console.log('data --------------', data);
      data.name = 'somename'; // will add new column with same data in all rows
      console.log('data after pushing ----------', data);
      results.push(data);
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('error ------------', err);
      reject();
    })
    .on('finish', () => {
      console.log();
      console.log('all the csv strings parsed to objects -------------', results);
    })
    .pipe(csv.stringify({ header: true }))
    .pipe(writeStream);
  });
  return p;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55275708/edit) the answer and add the information there.